# generating hmacSha256 value in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have used hmacSha256() method given in wiki. it is generating different HMAC-SHA256 byte array. is there any standard library to use HMAC-SHA256 in QT/ C++ ?

Comment: Which wiki?  What do you mean "different HMAC byte array"?  Do you mean that it is not generating the expected authentication tag when using one of the known answer tests (thank you NIST) for HMAC SHA256?  Please show your code.

Comment: Yes. It is not generating expecting authentication tags for the know input and output. I am referring to the "hmacSha256()" method given in  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QMessageAuthenticationCode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessageauthenticationcode.html).